# How to insert dynamic HTML from a URL using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototypejs

I want to be able to include a dynamic chunk of HTML in a page using javascript.

I wrote a servlet which returns a chunk of HTML, http://mydomain.com/dynamic.jsp  It produces some HTML ( minus head, body tags ) like this:

```
<div>
     Current Weather : 89F
</div>
```

How can I get that dynamic chunk of HTML into the page using a line of Javascript?

What is the simplest way?  I wonder if I need to wrap what the servlet produces in XML tags or in JSON format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JQuery's .load() function is handy for loading data from a server, and you can dynamically put the HTML anywhere you want using the callback.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Note that this will only work if both scripts run on the same domain.

Comment: You are right, it works fantastic, except if I want to call a URL on another domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use prototypejs, take a look here: http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax